# Переменная не видна в скрипте

Tags: python, python-3.x, bottle

Заранее пардон за большой объём вопроса, но я не знаю как сделать мин. воспроизводимый пример. Есть форк замечательного проекта https://github.com/iglov/sysdweb , там в конфиг добавили новую переменную `auth` и на её основе в функции [login](https://github.com/iglov/sysdweb/blob/master/sysdweb/server.py) определяется откуда сверять переданные `user, password` . У меня же стоит задача опционально убрать авторизацию. То есть, при отсутствии `auth` или `auth = none` , **как я думаю** , нужно убирать декоратор `@auth_basic(login)` чтоб login/pass вообще не запрашивало. Там даже есть для этого функция

```
def if_auth(condition, decorator):
    return decorator if condition else lambda x: x
```

Куда следует первым аргументом отдавать что-то, что будет принимать значение true/false. Я туда пробовал отдать этот несчастный `auth`, но проблема очевидно в областях видимости, потому что `server.py` не знает что такое `auth` даже если явно определить его где-то в начале как `auth = config.get('DEFAULT', 'auth', fallback=None)` - интерпретатор резонно возмутится о незнании `config`.

Вопрос, по-большей части, в *правильном* решении, так как я могу либо захардкодить там этот auth, либо объявить там `config` (но это не точно). Что бы в этом случае сделал опытный, сильный python-программист? :)

Comment: То ли я не пойму к чему тут эта ссылка, то ли Вы не читали ничего, кроме заголовка. В любом случае убрал его, чтоб не смущать лишний раз :)

Comment: Он инициализирован в другом месте и мне непонятно почему именно в этой области переменная невидна, но при этом в функциях вызываемых колбэком всё прекрасно работает. Вопрос поставлен именно так, как он поставлен - интересует best practice. Если Вы считаете что для того, чтоб увидеть там переменную нужно пройти по ссылке (aka науичиться, как я понял, по поводу и без перечитывать конфиг) - ок, спасибо, я Вас услышал! ^_^

Comment: Варианты: 1 - импортировать config из того файла, где он виден. 2 - определить функцию-геттер, которая вернет этот конфиг оттуда, где он виден, импортировать эту функцию, запросить конфиг где он нужен. И т.д. Сейчас в вопросе недостаточно информации для ответа: например, не известно как взаимодействуют модули где есть конфиг, и где его нет. Разбираться в этом "замечательном проекте" вряд ли кто-то будет.

Comment: Кстати, в принципе никто не мешает прочитать этот же конфиг в текущем модуле. Не совсем труъ вариант, но тоже имеет право на жизнь.